# Is there a name for this property of a binary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a name for a binary operation $*$ that is associative, with an left and right identity element $1$ and such that for all $x$ and $y$:

$$x*y*x=x*y$$

The context of this question is a kind of programming language where $*$ represents object composition: $x*y$ means "take $x$, then apply modifications represented by $y$". When both objects have a common ancestors, I don't want that ancestor $C$ to override the changes in $x$, so that $(C*x)*(C*y)$ must be equal to $C*x*y$. If this would match with a well-known mathematical structure, I could get this concept on a firmer footing. Note that the operation is obviously not commutative: $y$ has more priority than $x$ in $x*y$.

Note that the set union $\cup$ satisfies this property.

Comment: It satisfies $x^2=x$ for all $x$, so every element is an idempotent.

Comment: What do you mean by "identity element $1$"?  Do you mean left identity, right identity, both?  And, have you got an example in mind?  These things tend to be more interesting if there is an actual example.

Comment: @Dietrich OK, but if every element is idempotent, does it imply $x*y*x=x*y$ ?

Comment: @lulu, yes, I mean left and right identity.

Comment: @lulu: That was my mistake, I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @Joe No worries. $\quad$

Comment: Note:  the set theoretic example is a good one.  I'd add that to the post.  Anyway, I am unaware of a name for such an operation.

Comment: @lulu I've added all these elements and a description of what motivates my question

Comment: Very clear, thanks!  Good question (+1).  As I say, I am not aware of a term in standard use which covers this, but given the examples it seems like a natural concept.

Comment: Thanks! This conversation already helped me :)